# Interactions with Resalor (Prucalopride)

Tags: medications, side-effects

Resalor (Prucalopride) is not available in the United States, and thus no information for it is available on WebMD.

Is it safe to take both Resalor and Diflucan (Fluconazole)?  Is there anything one must avoid while taking Resalor (sunlight, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resolor (Prucalopride)](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/medicines/digestive-health/a8689/resolor-prucalopride/)

- > This medicine can cause diarrhoea which, if severe, can reduce the
  >   effectiveness of oral contraceptive pills at preventing pregnancy. If
  >   you are taking the pill for contraception and you experience severe
  >   diarrhoea while taking this medicine, you should follow the
  >   instructions for diarrhoea described in the leaflet provided with your
  >   pills. You may need to use an additional method of contraception, eg
  >   condoms.
- It should not be taken while pregnant or breast feeding
- Based on the common side effects, it may be best to avoid activities that require a lot of focus like driving and handling machinery depending on symptoms.

> Disturbances of the gut such as indigestion, flatulence, vomiting and
>   abnormal bowel sounds. Decreased appetite. Fatigue. Dizziness.

In the article, [Prucalopride. In chronic constipation: poorly documented risks](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21648173) this statement was made as to the risk identified.

> In practice, prucalopride should be avoided. It is better to focus on
>   lifestyle and behavioural changes, and rational use of laxatives.

- Other sites also suggest avoiding spicy foods when taking as it can cause feeling sick or abdominal pain.

Risks

> Increases in heart rate and blood pressure were observed in pigs and
>   dogs treated with prucalopride. Prucalopride seems to increase
>   prolactin levels. Tumours of the liver and thyroid were observed in
>   rats. Prucalopride also carries a risk of poorly defined
>   pharmacokinetic and pharmacodynamic interactions. Prucalopride may
>   reduce the efficacy of oral contraceptives. Miscarriages were reported
>   in clinical trials.

For medications that should be or shouldn't be taken with this medication a health care professional should be consulted. As for Diflucan interactions I cannot find any evidence against or for its interaction with Resorol.